# How could I create a cross platform interprocess communication between .NET and Java?

Tags: c#, java, mono, cross-platform, ipc

I want to develop a certain plugin/extension, which needs to run in eclipse and has to integrate with another (java) plugin, but it has to collect data from .NET assemblies (using [mono's cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil)).

So my question is how should I create this relation between the Java code and the .NET?
I know that I could use mono to run the .net application on for instance Linux, but I have 2 problems, I would like that the Java plugin starts the .NET application, and the second problem how to let the Java plugin make certain calls to the .NET application.

For this communication between these two applications, I would like to be platform independent so that the same binaries could run in both Windows, OSX and Linux. Another perhaps important fact is that the results of the calls could contain pretty big collection of objects.

Or perhaps it would be better/possible to host a .NET assembly inside of java and call it directly?

**Update**:
I think an ideal answer would solve the following questions:

- How to start/invoke the .NET assembly/application from the Java side. (cross platform)
- How to communicate with the .NET assembly
- What impact these choices have on the modifiability

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Communication between applications.

How to let a java application communicate with a .net application

**Transportation**

How to transport information between java and .net applications.

- Sockets - connections can be left open and both sides can send stuff (= act as client)
- WebServices - no connections are kept open, event handling will not work very well

**Serialization**

How to convert objects into something that can easily be transported.

- Plain XML - Easy to get started. Both java and .net have great XML support
- SOAP - Great if you want to expose an API for everyone to use. A bit complex.
- Protobof - Googles serialization protocol. Lot's of different implementations exist.
- Custom made binary serialization - Built your own serialization library

### How to load a .net assembly from java

Run the java application in mono ;)

http://www.ikvm.net/

Comment: I wouldn't want to impose the user of the plugin to load eclipse in mono ;)

Comment: Although it is doable :-) http://developers.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=03/05/10/2127222

Comment: That's just eclipse running.. not to mention all those plugins ;) but no, I wouldn't see ikvm as a solution for this problem.

Comment: You can always communicate through the stdin/stdout. Old way but always portable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Tcp/Ip to let them communicate

Comment: One could use it, but it requires a lot of core level knowlwdge of things.And in my opnion it's a bit complex.